# Output redireccting to file

Tags: ruby

I am getting two outputs in my code, one is a string and one is an array,
I Would like to redirect those two o/ps to one(same) file.
But only array value will be redirected to file others not.
I tried to use `$stdout = File.new( 'env.filename', 'w' )`

my output should be on file as below.

```
node = ["tes1", "test3, "test2""]
nodename = test1
```

My code is

```
$stdout = File.new( 'env.filename', 'w' ) 

puts "node = #{node_names.push(key)}" 
$stdout = STDOUT if value['tag'] == 'Hello world' 
$stdout = File.open( 'env.file', 'w' ) 

puts "nodename = #{key}" $stdout = STDOUT 

end
```

Comment: My code is  $stdout = File.new( 'env.filename', 'w' )
    puts "node = #{node_names.push(key)}"
   $stdout = STDOUT
   if value['tag'] == 'Hello world'
     $stdout = File.open( 'env.file', 'w' )
       puts "nodename = #{key}"
     $stdout = STDOUT
    end

Comment: Edit your post; don’t add more detail in a comment.

Comment: If you are on Linux, it is probably easier (and more useful) do do the output on stdout (therefore you do not mess around with anything in ruby, just use `puts`) and learn about redirection (`ruby myrubyprogram.rb > outputofmyrubyprogram.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening and closing the file

```rb
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
string = "xyz"

f = File.new("test.txt", "w")
f.write("#{string}\n") # Don't forget to add \n for new line 
f.write("#{array}")
f.close
```

After this script `test.txt` will be:

```
xyz
["a", "b", "c"]
```